# When I "simulate('click')" on wrapper child component button which calls onClick function, root component props doesn't updating

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to React and googled a lot of sources but could not solve my problem...

When I click on button via "simulate(click)" it works and I can see the right result of my test 'calls the props.onPointDelete'. But after this I should see new props of this wrapper (pointsList) which received from root App component where I have onClick handler. And it is not updated. It's the second test 'points.length equals 1' which failed. PointsList component is functional component.

I tried to update my wrapper via afterEach() function, and it's not working. Maybe this problem is somehow connected with mount() way of my wrapper? But I can't use shallow() way, because I need to access child of child component of my wrapper for my current tests. Can you help me please?

> PointsList.spec.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import PointsList from './PointsList';

describe('PointsList component', () => {
const mockOnPointDelete = jest.fn();

const props = {
    points: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Point 1',
        coordinates: [55.50, 57.50]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Point 2',
        coordinates: [55.51, 57.51]
      }
    ],
    onPointDelete: mockOnPointDelete,
    onDragEnd: () => {
    }
  };

  describe('PointsList component initial', () => {
    const pointsList = mount(<PointsList {...props} />);

    describe('when deleting first point', () => {
      pointsList.find('li').at(1).find('.btn.btn-delete').simulate('click');

      afterEach(() => {
        pointsList.update();
      });

      it('calls the props.onPointDelete', () => {
        expect(mockOnPointDelete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      });

      it('points.length equals 1', () => {
        expect(pointsList.prop('points')).toHaveLength(1);
      });

    });

  })
});
```

> PointsList.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Droppable, Draggable, DragDropContext} from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import RoutePoint from '../RoutePoint';

const PointsList = (props) => {

  const {points, onPointDelete, onDragEnd} = props;

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Droppable droppableId="pointsDroppable">
        { (provided) => (
          <ul className='list-group'
              ref={provided.innerRef}>
            { points.map((point, i) => {
              const {id, ...itemProps} = point;
              return (
                <Draggable key={id} draggableId={'draggable-' + id} index={i}>
                {provided => (
                  <li className='list-group-item'
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.draggableProps}
                      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                  >
                    <RoutePoint onPointDelete={() => onPointDelete(id)} {...itemProps}/>
                  </li>
                )}
                </Draggable>
              );
            })}
            {provided.placeholder}
          </ul>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
};

export default PointsList;
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain btn-delete element you're referring to. The test is messy. `pointsList.find('li').` and `mount()` reside in `describe` block. Nothing but `it` and `before`/`after` should reside there.

Comment: Thanks for reply! So I should write test in component where I have 'btn-delete' element and check for "toHaveBeenCalledTimes" event there, right?
And the second question is where I can read good tone rules when writing tests, can you advise please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing an integration test within unit testing. What you have above is unit testing. Since you've only mounted (you could just use `shallow` instead of `mount`) the `PointList` stateless function and mocked the `onPointDelete` function, `jest` has no awareness of the `parent` nor its methods. In simple terms, you've isolated your test to the `child`, **not the parent + child**. You're not calling the parent's `onPointDelete` method, you're just calling a fake/mocked function!

If you want to do an integration test with **parent + child**, then `mount` the `parent` that contains the `child`, set the parent's `state` (same as you did above for `props`, just use `parent.setState(...)`), do **not** mock the `onPointDelete` function, and now test for `state` and/or `prop` changes.

---

**Here's an example of integration and unit testing**: https://codesandbox.io/s/p3ro0615nm (I'm using custom `shallowWrap` and `mountWrap` functions that you can find more info about in `tests/utils/index.js` -- you can run the tests by clicking on the `Tests` tab at the bottom of the screen next `Console` and `Problems`)

The test in `containers/LOAs/__tests__/LOAs.test.js` is an integration test. This test steps through multiple components and checks for overall proper functionality between parent and children nodes, as well as, checks for `state` updates. I left some tests blank, so if you wish, you can fill them in for practice.

The test in `components/LoaList/__tests__/loaList.test.js` is a unit test -- note that this test is unnecessary since it's already covered in the above integration test, but it's here for example purposes of isolating the child component from the parent. This tests checks for child component functionality, `prop` validation, and mock function calling.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to using tests and especially in frontend. Now I will distinguish these types of tests :) But I don't understand **"(you could just use shallow instead of mount) "** because if I use shallow I can't access to my button ".btn-delete". May be I need to write test in child component where I can't access button ".btn-delete" with shallow? (as advised @estus in the comments under my question) And the second question is clarification - did I understand correctly that for now (with my described tests) I can only check if my parent function "onPointDelete" was called?

Comment: When using `shallow`, you can use `find('...').dive()` to find the button. However, if you feel that you're using `dive()` too many times, then use `mount` instead. And yes, `onPointDelete` is a mocked (faked) function when you set it as `jest.fn()`. In this case, you'll only be able to see how many times it's been called.

Comment: Updated the answer to include integration and unit testing examples.